# How to cancel newline character warning in the Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

anyone knowed that how to cancel newline character warning in the Pycharm? like the below picture.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself.
It's because I didn't cancel the search result when I use vim command :/$/ to search $. And the problem has solved by cancel the search result.